# Fix Video timelines

Tags: video, dvd, ripping, mpeg, timeline

So, I have been going through and riping all of my DVD's and it seems that the way to get the highest quality out of these is to have DVD Shrink de-encrypt, rip, and decompress, the DVD's. After that I usually end up with a high quality (high size) set of .vob files in a classic DVD structure. Then I use a python script that I wrote to automate the process of finding the title sequence and then combining all of the title sequences' .vob files together into one file(similar to the "copy /b" command in windows), and then changing the extension to .mpg (a more widely supported format then .vob).

This allows me to get a high quality rip in about 40 min.

The problem comes in playing the files. I need all of the ripped dvd's to play on my media computer using windows media center but windows media center (and vlc for that matter) all think that the video files are anywhere from 5 min. to 0 min. which is not a problem (the video will still play all the way through) but if you want to pause it, when it is unpaused the video will start all the way over (Also fast forward and rewind don't work).

I suspect that it is something wrong with the way the timeline is encoded in the video file, various forums on the internet recommended using virtualdub to fix the errors. But when I try to open the file virtual dub says that the file is not in mpeg-1 encoding and may be in mpeg-2. Is there any way to fix this?

PS: I am aware that there was a similar question but it hasn't had any activity for 2 months and is dealing more with wmv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DVD [VOBs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VOB) are modified [MPEG-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-2) [program streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_program_stream), while the .mpg extension is more widely associated with [MPEG-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-1).

I think your video players are confused by the file extension.  I'd try:

- (a) leaving the files with the .VOB extension,
- (b) trying other common extensions (.m2v, .m2p, .mpeg2 are possible alternatives), or
- (c) encoding the video into another format (H.264 or MPEG-4/XviD/DivX, in a Matroska/MKV or AVI container).

If your video players have the same trouble with (a) or (b), revamp your ripping process.  The two areas of concern are your "decompression" with DVD Shrink, and your combining-vobs-into-one-file procedure.  Try playing the original VOBs before they get combined; if that has the same problem, even with VLC, then you should try a different ripper program (eg DVD Decrypter).

If the uncombined VOBs *don't* show the same playback problem, your combination procedure is incorrect.  If you really need them combined, you may be able to run them through an MPEG-2 encoder (eg TMPGenc) to properly combine the VOBs into a real MPEG-2 file.  I expect when done properly this will only rewrite the container format, not transcode the video/audio streams.

Comment: and that will still maintain the quality? (Which is extremely important)

Comment: @josh: encoding into an h.264 or MPEG-4 file will be a transcode, which will lose some quality (tho how much depends on the encoder settings).  i haven't worked directly with a VOB->MPEG-2 encoding process, so i'm not certainl, but if all it's doing is converting the *container* format, you won't lose any quality -- there's no altering of the video/audio streams, just how they're packaged.